# I am getting "timeoutException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" during call of another function

Tags: selenium, nullpointerexception, automation

I am getting "timeoutException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" during call of another function.

Here is my code:

```
package AEC.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

// Import package pageObject.*

import Qa_pages.Constants;
import Qa_pages.Admin_Login;
import Qa_pages.Admin_Logout;
import Qa_Base.BasePage;


public class PageObjectModel extends Constants  {

private static WebDriver driver =null ;
private static WebElement element ;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      BasePage.Openbrowser();
    //WebDriver driver =new ChromeDriver();

      BasePage.maximize();
    //driver.manage().window().maximize();
      BasePage.Geturl();
      BasePage.timeout();

      System.out.print("timeout");


     Admin_Login.txtbx_UserName(driver).sendKeys(Constants.UserName);

     Admin_Login.txtbx_Password(driver).sendKeys(Constants.Password);

     Admin_Login.btn_LogIn(driver).click();

    Admin_Logout.Navigate_home().click();


    driver.quit();

}

}
```

Here, Admin_Login is a class of another package and txtbx_UserName is the function of that class. During execution of this function an error is thrown.

Comment: INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
timeoutException in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Qa_pages.Admin_Login.txtbx_Password(Admin_Login.java:40)
 at Qa_pages.HomePage.main(HomePage.java:45)

Comment: `TimeoutException` and `NullPointerException` are two very different things. Which one is it? post the stack trace. And how do you expect to get help on a method you didn't post?

Answer (score 0):

The reference 'driver' you passed in methods is set to value null. you must initialize that before execution.you have commented initialization code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER);    
driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: yes because without initializing it is getting executed my point is something else.